# Convert string to all lower case without built-in functions

Tags: python, string

```
#variable defination#
lower="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
upper="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
valid=True
x=0
g=0


string=input("enter a string:")

#data validation#
for char in string:
  if char in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
     valid=True
  else:
     valid=False

#finding the character#
if valid:
  for char in string:
    g+=1
    for ele in upper:
      if char!=ele:
       x+=1


print(lower[x]+string[g::])
```

**I can't get it to work, it keeps iterating through the entire string without the condition ever being met. **

Answer (score 1):

Since you are allowed to use lowercase and uppercase character inputs, you can create a dictionary mapping between them and use `str.join` with a list comprehension:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase

d = dict(zip(ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase))

string = input("enter a string:")

res = ''.join([d.get(i, i) for i in string])
```

It's not clear whether this satisfies your "no in-built function" requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to minimize changes from your original code (But remember, it's obvious that other solutions are much better.)

```
#variable defination#
lower="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
upper="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

string=input("enter a string:")

#data validation#
valid = True
for char in string:
  if char not in lower + upper:
     valid=False

#finding the character#
if valid:
  result = ""
  for char in string:
    if char in lower:
      result += char
    else:
      # uppercase character
      for i in range(len(upper)):
        if char == upper[i]:
          result += lower[i]
          break

  print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create mapping(dictionary) between `uppercase` and `lowercase` alphabets such that `upper_to_lower[uppercase]` should give you `lowercase`. You may refer below implementation as reference though.

```
import string

def to_lower_case(word):
    # construct auxilliary dictionary to avoid ord and chr built-in methods
    upper_to_lower = {}
    for index in range(len(string.ascii_uppercase)): # this is 26 we can use it as constant though
        upper_to_lower[string.ascii_uppercase[index]] = string.ascii_lowercase[index]

    result = ''
    for alphabet in word:
        if alphabet in string.ascii_uppercase:
            result += upper_to_lower[alphabet]
        else:
            result += alphabet

    return result

# sample input
In [5]: to_lower_case('ANJSNJN48982984aadkaka')                                
Out[5]: 'anjsnjn48982984aadkaka'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write an `index` method to get the index of an uppercase character in the `upper` string:

```
lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

def index(char):
    i = 0
    for c in upper:
        if char == c: return i
        i += 1
```

Then you can convert your string to lowercase like this:

```
#data validation#
# ...

#finding the character#
s = ''
if valid:
    for char in string:
        if char in lower: s += char
        else: s += lower[index(char)]

print(s)
```